# Flash AS3 Passing Variable From Child Class to Parent

Tags: actionscript-3, communication

I need to somehow do this, I know that I can use a localconnection, but I don't think that that's really necessary. I should be able to do something just as simple as *parent.foo()* to call the function foo.

This is my code that *isn't* working.

```
        if(this.parent)
            (this.parent as MovieClip).foo();
```

The error I'm getting is saying that the function foo doesn't exist, but I am sure that it does exist.

I don't know if this matters, but the child is a class, not a SWF or anything, I'm only saying this though because when I Googled possible solutions, the methods people use are with SWF's.

Anyways, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Despite the correctness of abhinav answer, I would encourage you to use an Event or Signal instead of this method. You will couple your classes to tightly with this approach.

MovieClip nested:

```
//use bubbling to enable event listening in deeper displayObjects
dispatchEvent(newEvent("somethingHappened", true));
```

MovieClip parent

```
child.addEventListener("somethingHappened", handlerFunction);

function handlerFunction(event:Event):void
{
     this.foo();
}
```

Comment: I concur, this is an overall healthier and more organised way to do things.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I didn't know that events worked like that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your class is added to the parent as a child.

Then, you can just say `YourClass(parent).foo();`

Additionally, any deeply nested class can also call any parent in the hierarchy of display objects. For example : `ParentOfParentClass(parent.parent).foo();`